# Entity Framework override default property convention to ignore properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am rewriting a legacy system to use Entity Framework.  The old system had entities where half of the properties were mapped to DB columns and the other half not.  To indicate that a property had to be mapped, the property was decorated with a [Field] attribute.  All other properties were ignored.

This is the opposite of what EF does.  By convention, EF maps all public properties with a getter and setter to a DB field unless the property is decorated with [NotMapped] data annotation or Ignore is called on for that property using the fluent API on model creating.

I want to override the EF convention to work as the old system.  ie Ignore properties that do not have the FieldAttribute.  I know that this could be done by adding [NotMapped] to all the properties, but I'm looking for a way to do this dynamically so that i don't have to change every single entity (there are hundreds)

There's not system convention to remove or override for this that i can see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.aspx

I've tried the following code to call ignore using reflection with no luck :

```
modelBuilder.Properties().Configure((configuration) =>
            {
                var attributes = configuration.ClrPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false);
                var fieldAttribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(FieldAttribute) || x.GetType() == typeof(KeyAttribute));
                if (fieldAttribute == null)
                {

                    var entityMethod = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity");
                    var entityConfiguration = entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(configuration.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType).Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
                    MethodInfo ignoreMethod = entityConfiguration.GetType()
                                               .GetMethod("Ignore")
                                               .MakeGenericMethod(configuration.ClrPropertyInfo.PropertyType);
                    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(configuration.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType);
                    var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, configuration.ClrPropertyInfo.Name);
                    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(memberExpression, parameter);
                    ignoreMethod.Invoke(entityConfiguration, new[] { lambdaExpression });
                }
            });
```

This looks like it works, as the property is added to the ignore list of the entity configuration.  But EF still tries to map the property to a non existent DB field and throws an Invalid column exception.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Even if it's possible, it doesn't seem the right thing to do. I would stick with adding `NotMapped` and removing the existing attribute from the other properties. This should be possible with a find & replace regex probably

Comment: Thanks.  I definitely cannot remove the existing attributes.  The field attribute has various properties which are used throughout the system.  I was hoping to not mix data annotations and our own attributes.  I've already replaced most of the conventions with my own custom ones.  This was just the last bridge to cross.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the problem.  If i come at this from the TypeConventionConfiguration instead of the PropertyConventionConfiguration it works.  I probably had some bug in my code above.  This way i need to use less reflection...

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure((entityConfiguration) =>
                {                    
                    const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;                    
                    foreach (var propertyInfo in entityConfiguration.ClrType.GetProperties(bindingFlags))
                    {
                        var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false);
                        var fieldAttribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(FieldAttribute) || x.GetType() == typeof(KeyAttribute));
                        if (fieldAttribute == null)
                        {
                            entityConfiguration.Ignore(propertyInfo);
                        }
                    }
                });
```