# prevent Entity Framework Core from mapping columns of super-classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've a base class for all the entities of my application.

```
 public class BaseEntitiy {
     public void ValidateModel() {...}
 }
```

It contains common functionalities like the method `ValidateModel`.

After a while I decided that it would be useful to have (for all the entities, so in the base class) an `IsNew` boolean property that contains the fact that a record is new or is taken from a database (BTW, I find it useful to have this information as a property even if EF Core traces this information in its context; here however is just an example of a property that doesn't have an associated field on the table, could be anything else).

Such a property has to be written like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public bool IsNew { get; set;}
```

Great care should be put when manipulating base class, because if you miss to specify `[NotMapped]` to a new property, next time you generate a migration EF Core will try to add it to *all* the sub-entities's tables.
Is it possible to 'revert' the mapping/non mapping behavior? 
The normal behavior is to map public properties unless they have `[NotMapped]` attribute.
It would be: for superclasses, maybe explicitly marked in some way, having the public properties not mapped unless explicitly declared.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of, or else at least related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36599816/1220550